# Error in downloading C++ exstension for visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio

just downloaded Visual Studio Code and try to download the extension for formatting c++ code,but it can't complete downloading giving error:

`Updating C/C++ dependencies...`

```
Downloading package 'C/C++ language components (Windows)'  Failed. Retrying... Failed. Retrying... Failed. Retrying...Waiting 8 seconds... Failed. Retrying...Waiting 16 seconds... Failed. Retrying... Done!
Downloading package 'ClangFormat (Windows)'  Failed. Retrying... Failed. Retrying... Failed. Retrying...Waiting 8 seconds... Failed. Retrying...Waiting 16 seconds... Failed. Retrying... Done!
Downloading package 'Visual Studio Windows Debugger'  Failed. Retrying... Failed. Retrying... Failed. Retrying...Waiting 8 seconds... Failed. Retrying...Waiting 16 seconds... Failed. Retrying... Done!

Installing package 'C/C++ language components (Windows)'
Failed at stage: installPackages
Error: end of central directory record signature not found
```

Extension:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools
The most popular one on the web.

I have connection to the internet and my firewall is just the normal windows security.
I have no idea what to do and where to start,because I am new to this kind of errors.Hope you to help me.

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this issue after VS updated and fixed it following below steps.

1. Download the corresponding version of C/C++ extension vsix file  from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/releases. Case I used the VS installed on Windows to visit the code on the Linux host. So i need to install this vsix file for Linux(Ubunutu). So i download this one https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/releases/download/1.5.1/cpptools-linux.vsix
2. Open VS on the windows and press shift+ctrl+p and click the "Extensions: Install from VSIX". Brose to your VSIX file and install it through the VS.
3. there will be a reminder to reload window if VSIX file installed successfully.

C/C++ extension is ready now after next VS boot up.

Comment: When you encountered this issue, were you by any chance installing on a remote server? I'm having issues with my remote server but not local server. The vsix approach also doesn't seem to work on my remote server

Comment: sorry i missed prerequisites step, First you should connect to the remote host using the ssh-remote tools provided by VS code and also download this vsix file to remote host instead of local host. Then follow above steps to install C/C++ extension on remote host.

Answer (score 1):

You typically encounter this issue when your host machine has no access to an internet connection. Once you manually install the language server manually and installing the cpptools-linux.vsix (corresponding to the plugin version number ms-vscode.cpptools-<>.vsix found in your ~/.vscode-server/extensions), **it is necessary to disable updates.**

This is both from microsoft (to prevent version mismatch of client vs host for VS code) and for the extensions to prevent it from recurrently downloading the language server.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/694

Seems that it happens sometimes. Use the offline installers with all dependencies. It worked for me.